# Rust set different panic output for debug and release modes

Tags: error-handling, rust

I've got the following error formatting set up for my error type:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    match self {
        Self::BadArg(s) => write!(f, "InputError::BadArg: Failed to parse arg: \"{}\". {}",s, SEE_HELP),
    }
}
```

When I directly call `.unwrap()` it prints the following:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: BadArg("-ep")', src\main.rs:19:36
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

But if I instead call `.unwrap_or_else(|e|{println!("{}",e);exit(1)})` on the error and print it myself alongside `exit(1)` it prints the errors formatted string:

```
InputError::BadArg: Failed to parse arg: "-ep". Try --help for usage.
```

This is a bit of an issue because I would like to have the full panic information when I'm building on debug, but on release I would like the end user to just see the error output that I set up for my error and not a bunch of unnecessary info that doesn't make sense outside of a rust setting.

What I'm wondering is there a way to make it so on debug builds it prints the full panic but on release builds it instead prints the formatted version of the error? I'm aware of conditional compilation and the ability to get the profile using env, but I'm looking for a way to do it across the entire project for every panic without needing to set up a separate match to check the profile for each error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need to use conditional compilation everywhere. You could just make a single trait for it, then just call that.

```rust
pub trait FormattedUnwrap<T> {
    fn unwrap_or_fmt(self) -> T;
}

impl<T, E: Display> FormattedUnwrap<T> for Result<T, E> {
    fn unwrap_or_fmt(self) -> T {
        if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            self.unwrap()
        } else {
            self.unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                println!("{}", e);
                exit(1)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can just call `unwrap_or_fmt()` everywhere and it will be handled according to the build mode.

Comment: perfect! thank you! i spent the last two hours trying to configure a panic hook to do basically exactly this. i really need to get better at remembering to use traits.
one small thing for anyone that comes across this in the future, i needed to use Display+Debug for it to work properly